# Capital letters and numbers

Tags: capitalization

If I have a sentence beginning with a number, should I use a capital letter?
For example:

24 Other schools

or

24 other schools

Comment: Related (also possibly a duplicate of): [Capitalization rules when the sentence begins with a number](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/54740/3281)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the number, you do **not** use a capital.

However, in terms of style it is considered untidy to start a sentence with a number. You should either write the number in full or reword your sentence so that it does not begin with that number.

> - Twenty-four other schools...
> - Other schools, 24 in total,...

If your number contains a decimal point, this does not apply. In that case, writing the numbers in full would result in a very sloppy sentence. The word following the number is not capitalised:

> - 24,34% of all schools,...

Comment: It is also generally considered proper to write out small numbers (although where the dividing line is depends on the style guide; I've seen anywhere from 1-5 to 1-20) and even multiples of ten. Every style guide I've ever read has some version of this, but they are commonly ignored in informal writing.

Answer (score 2):

If the context of the sentence is formal enough that correctly capitalising or not is an issue, I'd recommend replacing the numerals with words.

*Twenty four other schools*

At least that removes any ambiguity as to how to capitalise.